# Changing the contents of Highcharts legend

Tags: highcharts, legend, scatter

When using Highcharts, is it possible to change the contents of the legend to display something other than the series?

For example, I have a scatter chart with just one series but with many elements, so that the element labels obstruct one another and are illegible:
Would it be possible to use the legend to display the element names instead of the series? (each member in the series has a different color so that it is possible to use the legend in this case)

---

**EDIT:**

It turns out there isn't any good way to do this, so I wrote my own custom legend.  You can find the code here: http://pastie.org/5115536

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Could you shift your code and create a series for each point instead of a single series of many points?

Comment: Yes, what you really have is multiple series. I suggest you go with @Mark & change your code to make multiple series with one point each. Mark removed my answer too, you rightly pointed that I got the question wrong.

Comment: I tried that but it's not an optimal solution. I ended up rendering my own custom legend in html.

Comment: I am running into a similiar issue. I would love to just show the stacks of a stacked barchart in the legend instead of the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts allows to show data points instead of series name in the in the legend. But, Unfortunately its only for Pie charts `type:pie`.

There is a default option available for the  Pie Chart though undocumented in the API.

```
legendType: 'point',
```

If you try to set it for other type of chart, Legend does not gets rendered.

Comment: Hi Hardik, thanks for your answer. I ended up rendering my own custon Legend in HTML.

Comment: @sangil: Good to hear that.. May be if you want to share. so that it may help other users..